# Binding Complex Model Entity With Raw SQL Query?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, orm, entity-framework-6

I have been using entity framework quite some and I can do complex model binding with entity itself easily, but when it comes to raw sql binding I cant find any solutions that is doing complex binding of relation db.

for example following is a entity to model code for product class-

```
var prodResult = db.products.Where(p => p.isActive == true).Select(p => new ComplexProductModel
                {
                    id = p.id,
                    dateCreated = p.date_created,
                    datePublished = null,
                    desc = p.product_desc,
                    images = db.products_images.Where(pi => pi.prod_id == p.id).Select(pi => pi.prod_img_thumb).ToList(),
                    summary = p.product_summary,
                    title = p.product_name + " " + p.product_code
                }).ToList();
```

This realizes data against complex Model holding a list type of string or class inside main Complex Model as per query requirements.

Now I tried running same generating query with raw sql execution, but the binding for images object is failing.

```
var rawComplexData = db.Database.SqlQuery<ComplexProductModel>(dynamicSearchQuery).ToList();
```

Is there any solution for this situation, what I am getting is 10 rows of data(for this example) with images null which should be 7 rows with duplicate fetched images going into `List<string> images` for the `ComplexProductModel`.

Here is the complex product model for better understanding the code:

```
public ComplexProductModel {
        long? id { get; set; }
        string title { get; set; }
        string desc { get; set; }
        string summary { get; set; }
        List<string> images { get; set; }
        DateTime? datePublished { get; set; }
        DateTime? dateCreated { get; set; }
    }
```

As per @tchelidze request here is `dynamicQuery` which is basically what i grabbed from what entity framework was generating itself :

```
SELECT 
    [Project2].[C1] AS [C1], 
    [Project2].[id] AS [id], 
    [Project2].[date_created] AS [date_created], 
    [Project2].[C2] AS [C2], 
    [Project2].[product_desc] AS [product_desc], 
    [Project2].[product_summary] AS [product_summary], 
    [Project2].[C3] AS [C3], 
    [Project2].[C4] AS [C4], 
    [Project2].[prod_img_thumb] AS [prod_img_thumb]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Extent1].[id] AS [id], 
        [Extent1].[product_desc] AS [product_desc], 
        [Extent1].[product_summary] AS [product_summary], 
        [Extent1].[date_created] AS [date_created], 
        1 AS [C1], 
        CAST(NULL AS datetime2) AS [C2], 
        [Project1].[prod_img_thumb] AS [prod_img_thumb], 
        CASE WHEN ([Extent1].[product_name] IS NULL) THEN N'' ELSE [Extent1].[product_name] END + N' ' + CASE WHEN ([Extent1].[product_code] IS NULL) THEN N'' ELSE [Extent1].[product_code] END AS [C3], 
        [Project1].[C1] AS [C4]
        FROM  [dbo].[products] AS [Extent1]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN  (SELECT 
            [Extent2].[prod_id] AS [prod_id], 
            [Extent2].[prod_img_thumb] AS [prod_img_thumb], 
            1 AS [C1]
            FROM [dbo].[products_images] AS [Extent2] ) AS [Project1] ON [Project1].[prod_id] = [Extent1].[id]
        WHERE 1 = [Extent1].[isActive]
    )  AS [Project2]
    ORDER BY [Project2].[id] ASC, [Project2].[C4] ASC
```

Comment: post a `dynamicSearchQuery` too.

Comment: ok putting that in edit

Comment: why do a -1 on this question?

Comment: @tchelidze i have edited the question with more info

Comment: Why? :-) (as asked below, but here for completeness)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could introduce a new Object, e.g. let's call it `ComplexProductDto` and it should match exactly to the query result structure as it is returned from SQL, example:

```
// Please adjust...
public class ComplexProductDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ProductDesc { get; set; }
    ...
    public string ProdImgThumb { get; set; }
}
```

Now that data is going to be flattened and ungrouped, containing duplicate records, which you could group in memory using Linq.

```
var rawComplexData = db.Database.SqlQuery<ComplexProductDto>(dynamicSearchQuery).ToList(); 
var prodResult = rawComplexData
  .GroupBy(x => new
  {
      x.Id,
      x.ProductDesc,
      // List all but Image...
  })
  .Select(x => new ComplexProductModel
  {
      id = x.Key.Id,
      desc = x,Key.ProductDesc,
      .... // etc.
      images = x.Select(i => i.ProdImgThumb).ToList()
  });
```

The code might be not 100% correct but you get the point. The technique is to retrieve ungrouped data and group it back to desired structure.

Comment: i was thinking about the same, but i truly wanted to avoid another step if entity can do it itself. i mean the in-built function does it. any ways i will wait for alternates and if there are no better solutions i will go with your answer.

Comment: also this begs another issue in case Model needs to be generic then what?

Comment: 1) `db` is a specific data context, it has the knowledge of all entites, relationships etc., but by using `db.Database` you basically leave that level and enter raw access. You basically operate outside the Entity Framework DB Context. 2) The "unflattening" technique is specific to objects used, a generic solution is not what you want to build, you don't want to reinvent the Entity Framework :-) Maybe, the source for a better solution lies within the *why*, what is the purpose of bypassing the EF built in functions? Else, this is going to be a more then bumpy road to continue with.

Comment: ouch that will be really bumpy road :P